# Getting the error the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type in an anchor program?

Tags: anchor

I am creating a zero-copy account and I am getting this error. This is a type error it seems and I feel I am missing something please help.
[image]

Comment: please replace the screenshot with text in a code block to improve this question's seo

Answer (score 1):

The struct OTC cannot implement the Copy trait, because Vec is not Copy. Hence it is giving an error `the trait Copy may not be implemented for this type;`.
Here's a good explanation of why some `T` can't derive the `Copy` trait.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-cant-my-type-be-copy

Answer (score 0):

Vec can't use `zero-copy`, you have to use a fixed-length array.

It's also easier to use `#[repr(C)]` with `zero-copy`, easier to align items.